# Extjs ajax code refactor

Tags: javascript, refactoring, extjs

I have this kind of ajax code repeated lot of places. How can I refactor this into a single method so it will still allow different behavior on success or failure.

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url : 'ajax.php' , 
    params : { action : 'getDate' },
    method: 'GET',
    success: function ( result, request ) { 
    Ext.MessageBox.alert('Success', 'Data return from the server: '+     result.responseText); 
    },
    failure: function ( result, request) {  Ext.MessageBox.alert('Failed', result.responseText); 
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
MyAjaxRequest = Ext.extend ( Ext.Ajax.request, {
     url : 'ajax.php' ,
     params : { action : 'getDate' },
     method: 'GET',
     success: function ( result, request ) {
        Ext.MessageBox.alert ('Success', 'Data return from the server: '+    result.responseText);
     },
     failure: function ( result, request) {
        Ext.MessageBox.alert('Failed', result.responseText);
      }
} );
```

by extending class (namespaces up to you) you still able to manipulate url, params, method, success, and failure. if not setup - defaults are there

Comment: Should I use `success`/`failure` or just `callback`?

Comment: Good answer, how to call `MyAjaxRequest`.

Comment: it is a class: yourVariable = new MyAjaxRequest ( { } );

Comment: `Ext.Ajax.request` is a method in class `Ext.Ajax` right? How it can be extended to create a class?

Answer (score 3):

Okay, this question is kind of old, but there arguably a more flexible way to do this. It's really important to realize that Ext.Ajax is a *singleton* -- that is, it is already a unique pre-instantiated class. "Extending" a singleton doesn't make much sense, and a separate function may be unnecessarily confusing and/or limiting later on.

You can add your own special Ajax request function like this:

```
Ext.Ajax.dateRequest = function(myObj){
   // set the pre-configured parameters here
   myObj.url = 'ajax.php';
   myObj.params = { action: 'getDate'};
   myObj.method = 'GET';
   // call the original request function with the modified config object
   this.request(myObj); 
};
```

So now you can change your repeated Ajax requests to:

```
Ext.Ajax.dateRequest({
   success: yourSuccessFunction
   ,failure: yourFailureFunction
});
```

The benefit to this is that you can easily add pre-configured parameters to your "dateRequest" function, AND you can add addition parameters to each Ajax request (like a different timeout) without rewriting anything.

EDIT: Yikes! I originally posted a solution below that I thought would "clone" Ext.Ajax, but it still merely overrode the singleton.

This is a quote by "Saki" (Ext guru) a couple of years ago. He's referring to a clone function he wrote for regular object/arrays:

> The clone function is in no case meant to clone classes or
>   instantiated Ext objects. It is almost impossible as these install
>   event handlers almost always so cloning would definitely lead to
>   unpredictable results.

The singleton is a "instantiated Ext object" and thus cannot be extended or cloned easily. If you don't want to mess with Ext.Ajax directly, you can create a function (as already mentioned). Here is a somewhat more flexible form:

```
function dateRequest(myObj){
   myObj.url = 'ajax.php';
   myObj.params = { action: 'getDate'};
   myObj.method = 'GET';
   return Ext.Ajax.request(myObj);
}
```

Then call it with `dateRequest({success: successFunc, failure: failFunc})`.

Answer (score 2):

This code will achieve the same result:

```
function callme (callback) {
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url : 'ajax.php' , 
        params : { action : 'getDate' },
        method: 'GET',
        success: callback,
        failure: function ( result, request) {  Ext.MessageBox.alert('Failed', result.responseText); 
        } 
    });
}

callme(function ( result, request ) { 
    Ext.MessageBox.alert('Success', 'Data return from the server: '+     result.responseText); 
});
```

Comment: it will point to every time to callback function (you name it callme (second one) I guess it is typo ) ...